# Monitoring the recent apps

Tags: android, android-intent

I am writing an app which monitors which applications I am using the most in my Android device.

To do this I am using:

```
    final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final List<RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRecentTasks(20, ActivityManager.RECENT_WITH_EXCLUDED);

    for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) {

        Intent baseIntent = recentTasks.get(i).baseIntent;
        if(baseIntent != null) {

            Log.d("Text", "Lior: Application executed: " + i + ": baseIntent: " + baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName() + baseIntent.getComponent().getClassName());

        }
```

The problem with this is that is only gives me the recent apps, and not how many times each app was started.

To check by recent app I check if the app was now more recent than the last time I checked - this way I know it was run.

Given a time gap of about 3 hours from each call there might be an app that was called more than once and then I will only count it as one.

Is there a way to receive how many times an app was started given a time gap?

I know this is a specific question but if anyone encountered something like that it would be helpful. (maybe something with the intent?)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played around with widgets but maybe you could setup your app as one. Then every time an application is opened to add to an int tied to that application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but there are some inter apis.

```
private void setActivityController() {
    IActivityManager am = ActivityManagerNative.getDefault();
    try {
        am.setActivityController(new ActivityController());
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}




public class ActivityController extends IActivityController.Stub {

private static final String TAG = ActivityController.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public boolean activityResuming(String pkg) throws RemoteException {
    Log.e(TAG, "activityResuming -- "+pkg);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean activityStarting(Intent intent, String pkg)
        throws RemoteException {
    Log.e(TAG, "activityStarting -- "+pkg+" intent="+intent);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean appCrashed(String processName, int pid, String shortMsg, String longMsg,
        long timeMillis, String stackTrace) throws RemoteException {
    Log.e(TAG, "appCrashed -- "+processName);
    return true;
}

@Override
public int appEarlyNotResponding(String processName, int pid, String annotation)
        throws RemoteException {
    Log.e(TAG, "appEarlyNotResponding -- "+processName);
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int appNotResponding(String processName, int pid, String processStats)
        throws RemoteException {
    Log.e(TAG, "processName -- "+processName);
    return 0;
}
```

}